# How to display the user logged in time?

Tags: linux

Is there a command in linux to display the amount of time a user has logged in?
The 'who' command displays only the users connected..
how about the time a user is logged in?

Comment: Is there a difference?

Answer (score 0):

If you run `who -H` you can see the column names:

```
x-cash@runabout:~$ who -H
NAME     LINE         TIME             COMMENT
x-cash   tty7         2013-08-20 10:23 (:0)
x-cash   pts/0        2013-08-25 15:45 (:0)
```

As you can see, the column `TIME` is exactly what you're looking for. Just subtract that value from the actual time.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the output of `who` or `w` to get the time a user logged in. If you then parse the dates and compare them to "now", you can get how long a user has been logged in. For example, to get the time in minutes:

```
who | awk '{print $1,$3,$4}' | while read user time; do \
  echo $user $(($(($(date +%s) - $(date -d "$time" +%s)))/60)) minutes; done 

terdon 39 minutes
terdon 31 minutes
terdon 23 minutes
terdon 22 minutes
terdon 20 minutes
terdon 18 minutes
terdon 15 minutes
guest 15 minutes
terdon 13 minutes
terdon 12 minutes
```